Personalised ```\footcitetext``` in a ```column``` environment in beamer
I have a personalised \footcite that I would like to use in a columnenvironment in beamer. As mentionned in How can I stop \footcite from hijacking my beamer columns? , I use \footnotemark along with \footcitetext while in colummn environment in order to keep the two columns within the frame.
However, when I change the citation style of \footcitetext with \DeclareCiteCommand, it appears that the reference number of the \footnotemarkand \footcitetextdo not coincide, and that a footnote number is added at the place where I put the \footcitetext.
I guess that I did wrong with \DeclareCiteCommand, but I cannot figure out where as I am not very familiar with modifications of Latex commands.
Here you can find a MWE:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


% BIBLIOGRAPHY  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=1,style=authortitle]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Moore1965,
  author={Moore, Gordon E.},
  journal={IEEE Solid-State Circuits Society Newsletter}, 
  title={Cramming more components onto integrated circuits, Reprinted from Electronics, volume 38, number 8, April 19, 1965, pp.114 ff.}, 
  year={2006},
  volume={11},
  number={3},
  pages={33-35},
  keywords={Integrated circuits;Computers;Silicon;Films;Heating;Microwave amplifiers;Data mining},
  doi={10.1109/N-SSC.2006.4785860}
}
\end{filecontents}
    
    
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 


%% MODIFICATION OF \footcite CITATION STYLE
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote
]{}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{year}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{journaltitle}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}
    {, }%
    {\vspace{0cm}}

%% MODIFICATION OF \footcitetext CITATION STYLE
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnote]{}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{year}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{journaltitle}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}
    {, }%
    {\vspace{0cm}}

\mode<presentation>

%% BEAMER SETTINGS
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rmfamily}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
This is a first footcite in a frame \footcite{Moore1965} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5.5cm}
    This is a second citation but in a columns/column environment\footnotemark
\end{column}
\begin{column}{4.5cm}
    This is another column
\end{column}
\end{columns} 
\footcitetext{Moore1965}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

And the output I get:



You can make biblatex place its footnotes at the bottom of the frame like this:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


% BIBLIOGRAPHY  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=1,style=authortitle]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Moore1965,
  author={Moore, Gordon E.},
  journal={IEEE Solid-State Circuits Society Newsletter}, 
  title={Cramming more components onto integrated circuits, Reprinted from Electronics, volume 38, number 8, April 19, 1965, pp.114 ff.}, 
  year={2006},
  volume={11},
  number={3},
  pages={33-35},
  keywords={Integrated circuits;Computers;Silicon;Films;Heating;Microwave amplifiers;Data mining},
  doi={10.1109/N-SSC.2006.4785860}
}
\end{filecontents}
    
    
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 


%% MODIFICATION OF \footcite CITATION STYLE
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote
]{}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{year}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{journaltitle}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}
    {, }%
    {\vspace{0cm}}

%% MODIFICATION OF \footcitetext CITATION STYLE
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnote]{}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{year}%
    \printtext{, }%
    \printfield{journaltitle}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}
    {, }%
    {\vspace{0cm}}

\mode<presentation>

%% BEAMER SETTINGS
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rmfamily}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@warning{Nested notes}%
     \addspace\mkbibparens{#2}}
    {\unspace
     \ifnum\blx@notetype=\tw@
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
       {\csuse{blx@theendnote#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{end}{#2}}}}
       {\csuse{footnote}[frame]{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}}}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
This is a first footcite in a frame \footcite{Moore1965} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5.5cm}
    This is a second citation but in a columns/column environment\footcite{Moore1965}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{4.5cm}
    This is another column
\end{column}
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}


